# GeoAccessor (SEDF) spatial join is not working in ArcGIS Python API?

Tags: arcgis-pro, arcgis-python-api

I want make a spatial join with my two spatially enabled dataframes. But while doing a join between the two dataframes. I got below errors.

```
joined_sedf = sedf_cables.spatial.join(sedf_sub_assignment[['SHAPE']], how="inner", op="intersects")
```

[image]

Why does this error appear and how I will be able make a join between the two dataframes where one is polygon and another is one is a line feature?

Comment: probably one of the rows does not have geometry (null). How familiar are you with pandas?

Comment: i need to do it using spatially enabled dataframe  and not to use geopandas.

Comment: Please [Edit] the Question so that the error text is in the body of the Question (as text, and therefore searchable and legible). There isn't much less readable than red-on-black, so even if the image were legible, it would still be tough sledding for many.

Comment: SDEF is a pandas dataframe with geometry capabilities. I know you're not using geopandas. My point is, use the "apply" method and identify the missing geometries.

Answer (score 0):

```
spatial_relationship = 'intersects'

# Perform the spatial join
sedf_cable_joined = sedf_sub_assignment.spatial.join(sedf_cables, op=spatial_relationship)
```

After replace the code, as specified above i am able to make spatial join on both the dataframes.